# Do I have to make an ability check to stay mounted when my mount or I take damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage

If I am on my griffon from my casting of *greater steed*, and he or I take damage, is there normally a check to stay mounted?

Comment: Have you been through the PHB and read the relevant rules? What reason do you have for suspecting you would possibly be dismounted if you or your mount takes damage?

Comment: My always make a check, DM

Comment: It might be worthwhile adding that into the question (e.g. *"my DM always has us make a check to stay mounted when the mount or rider takes damage, is this normally the case? I've checked the PHB but can't find anything [if you have been through the PHB] that says as such"*). It can be helpful for us to know *why* you've asked the question, especially if that reason is "the DM says so", and [we do expect a little bit of research to be done before asking here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Not usually

There are three cases where you may be forced to dismount (all found in the Combat: Mounted Combat section of the Player's Handbook):

1. > If an effect moves your mount against its will while you're on it, you must succeed on a DC 10 Dexterity saving throw or fall off the mount, landing prone in a space within 5 feet of it.
2. > If you're knocked prone while mounted, you must make the same saving throw.
3. > If your mount is knocked prone, you can use your reaction to dismount it as it falls and land on your feet. Otherwise, you are dismounted and fall prone in a space within 5 feet it.

### But your GM could call for a check

The GM is the one that decides when ability checks are used

> The GM calls for an ability check when a character or monster attempts an action (other than an attack) that has a chance of failure. When the outcome is uncertain, the dice determine the results.

If your GM suggests that remaining mounted has a chance of failure (such as if you get hit by a boulder), then he/she is within his/her right to call for a check.

Comment: @Dndjunkie I added a small clarification from a different rule that appears to be important for your situation based on your comment

Comment: That rule doesn't actually say the GM can call for a check here: 'staying mounted' is not an action the PC is attempting; it is the default state.  If it were being done as an action, it'd take up most of the PC's turn and also they could dismount for free by incurring a hit on their  mount or self.